# ASP.NET MVC Form Submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, file-upload

I'm having a bit of a brain fart; it must be Monday...

I have an MVC form, which allow the user to submit an image.

The image is saved to a folder, then I want to redirect to another Controller and Action to display the image.

What are my options for passing the image name and path back to the controller action to display the graphic?

```
    // Handles the updload, contains a control (ascx) 
    // and the control's action method is in another controller
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // I want this page to display the image uploaded in the Upload.ascx control
    // that is in the index method above:
    public ActionResult Result()
    { 
        ViewData["MyImage"] = ???
    }
```

Thanks much.

Comment: You can haz Cheezburger? If this is what I think it is...you'll get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the image being stored? In your content area or in a database?  If it's in a database, then I'd construct the controller/action url to display that image form the db.  If it's in your content area, then you can construct the url based on the name of the uploaded file. I'd probably create a model rather than passing the url in view data, but view data is a valid (i.e., it works) alternative.

```
 public ActionResult Result( int id ) // db storage
 {
     return View( new UploadModel
                  {
                      ImageUrl = Url.Action( "display", "image", new { id = id }
                  } );
 }


 public ActionResult Result() // content area
 {
     var imageName = ... get image name from ???  ...
     return View( new UploadModel
                  {
                      ImageUrl = Url.Content( "~/content/images/uploads/" + iamgeName );
                  });
 }
```